# Critical Update: Require User Access to Apex Classes Invoked by Flow when running user = Automated Process

Tags: platform-event, critical-update, automated-process

**Given**

- [Critical Update Require User Access to Apex Classes Invoked by Flow](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_cruc_security.htm) is activated
- Apex trigger that subscribes to a Platform Event
- Trigger logic does DML
- Process Builder executes and makes Invocable Apex call

**When**

- Running user = Automated Process (*as of V46, by definition*)

**Then**

> Flow blows up with `Require User Access to Apex Classes Invoked by Flow`

But there's no way to assign the `Automated Process` user's Profile to any Apex class nor can you assign a Permission Set to `Automated Process` user

e.g.

```
insert new PermissionSetAssignment(
  AssigneeId = [select id from User where name = 'Automated Process'][0].Id,
  PermissionSetId = [select id from PermissionSet 
         where name = 'Classes_Automated_Process_User_Needs'][0].Id);


System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: 
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Can't assign permission set to this user,
                           user license doesn't match: []
```

Is there another way to assign Automated Process user to a Permission Set or give it access to this invocable apex class?

> Critical Update auto-activates 2019-11-30

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The real answer was provided by [Matt over on Salesforce Success](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003aTkQAI)

1. Get the ProfileId of Automated Process User using Dev Console

   ```
    SELECT ProfileId from User WHERE alias = 'autoproc'
   ```
2. Coerce the URL that edits Apex class access for a Profile

   ```
    /_ui/system/user/ProfileApexClassPermissionEdit/e?profile_id=theAutomatedProcessProfileId
   ```

and you'll get the familiar dialog to assign Apex classes to a Profile.

Comment: Wow. Just... wow.  Who says URL hacking is dead??

Answer (score 3):

After a call to SFDC Support, the answer seems to be:

"Call SFDC Support to enable Automated Process user access to invocable classes before enabling this Critical Update."

*Clearly unsatisfactory. Let's hope Winter 20 has a solution*.

> UPDATE: If you do call Support, they will tell you that you can self-serve by entering the Automated Process's ProfileId `00e36000000oZf3AAE` into the URL - but you'll get Insufficient Privileges if you do that *whereas if Support logs in as you, they do not get an error and can see the profile*.